# Memory Allocation Failure in C++(using new & delete)

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I am an ordinary student trying to code a Monte-Carlo Tree Search.

To do this, I made a struct named "Node", and tried to make new Node* pointers and allocate memory to them with "new", but my program keeps on crashing, and I would reeeeally appreciate some help.

Here's what my code looks like. Locations of failure are marked.

Thank you in advance.

```
Node* knell;
Node* treePolicy(Node* currentnode){
    puts("treepolicy");
    Node* temp=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    puts("Mem Allocated");
    Move save=MCTBoard.generateRandomLegalMove(currentnode->player);      ///works very well up to here.
    save.printMove();
    temp=findNode(currentnode,save);
    puts("Node Found");
    knell=new Node; 
    if(temp==NULL){
        free(temp);
        temp = new Node; ///crashes the second time treePolicy(Node*) is called.
        temp->setMove(save);
        temp->child.clear();
        currentnode->child.push_back(temp);
        temp->parent=currentnode;
        MCTBoard.playMove(save,currentnode->player);
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<=i;j++){
                for(int k=0;k<=i;k++){
                    temp->board[i][j][k]=MCTBoard.a[i][j][k];
                }
            }
        }
        temp->value=temp->visited=temp->win=temp->draw=0;
        temp->player=3-currentnode->player;
        knell=temp;
        //delete temp; -> even with this enabled, still crashes.
        return knell;///an infinite loop happens here, but that is another problem so...
    }
else{
    ///not important,and besides,I've not even reached here yet once.
}
```

}

actually there does exist a same problem in another function, but I feel that that is some other problem.

So, can anyone please tell me why it crashes??

Comment: Can you provide the definition for findNode(currentnode,save).

Comment: Don't use `malloc` and `free`. The counterpart of `new` is `delete`. Never pair `new` with `free` and vice versa

Comment: Don't use new and delete explicitly. Use things like `std::make_unique` or `std::make_shared` depending on the ownership model. This will relief you from your memory problems and prevent memory leaks.

Comment: If you are on Linux, run your program with valgrind. This will probably tell you where an object is deleted twice. If not, use gdb to step through your program.

Answer (score 2):

Let's walk through the life cycle of `temp`.

You allocated memory using `malloc`.

```
Node* temp=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

and then you are overriding the `temp` by return value of below function.

```
temp = findNode(currentnode,save);
```

then you are deleting it using `free`.

```
free(temp);
```

Memory above which you are freeing using `free` is returned from `findNode`. Most probably reason for the crash is that function returned memory allocated using `new` rather than `malloc`.

Comment: Wowowoah. Thanks for the answer! I didn't know that the memory is being allocated with new at temp=findNode . Oh and by the way, for the definition of findNode (Node* currentnode,Move save) You requested...In struct Node, there exists a vector<Move*> child and Move (defined elsewhere). What this does is that from the vector child, it finds the node that has the same MovePlayed as Move save and returns the node's pointer. If nonexistent, NULL is returned. I am very sorry for not being in a condition able to post codes right now.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of comments:

```
Node* knell;
```

why make `knell` a global variable?  Why not handle the assignment of the global outside of the function (perhaps something that looks like:

```
knell = treePolicy(currentNode);
```

) or something similar

```
Node* treePolicy(Node* currentnode){
    puts("treepolicy");
    Node* temp=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

No reason to malloc here.  You're going to overwrite later, so lets remove this line.

```
    puts("Mem Allocated");
    Move save=MCTBoard.generateRandomLegalMove(currentnode->player);      ///works very well up to here.
    save.printMove();
    temp=findNode(currentnode,save);
```

Here's a great place for auto.

```
    puts("Node Found");
    knell=new Node;
```

Like we said above, remove this.

```
    if(temp==NULL){
```

good place for nullptr

```
        free(temp);
```

we just determined `temp` was null.  No need to free

```
        temp = new Node; ///crashes the second time treePolicy(Node*) is called.
        temp->setMove(save);
        temp->child.clear();
        currentnode->child.push_back(temp);
        temp->parent=currentnode;
        MCTBoard.playMove(save,currentnode->player);
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<=i;j++){
                for(int k=0;k<=i;k++){
                    temp->board[i][j][k]=MCTBoard.a[i][j][k];
                }
            }
        }
        temp->value=temp->visited=temp->win=temp->draw=0;
        temp->player=3-currentnode->player;
        knell=temp;
```

Let's get rid of this

```
        //delete temp; -> even with this enabled, still crashes.
        return knell;///an infinite loop happens here, but that is another problem so...
```

Ok, so now there's no reason to return `knell`, but just return `temp`.

```
    }
else{
    ///not important,and besides,I've not even reached here yet once.
}
```

So the fixed up code should look like:

```
   Node* treePolicy(Node* currentnode){
        puts("treepolicy");
        Move save=MCTBoard.generateRandomLegalMove(currentnode->player);      ///works very well up to here.
        save.printMove();
        auto temp=findNode(currentnode,save);
        puts("Node Found");
        if(temp==nullptr){
            temp = new Node; ///crashes the second time treePolicy(Node*) is called.
            temp->setMove(save);
            temp->child.clear();
            currentnode->child.push_back(temp);
            temp->parent=currentnode;
            MCTBoard.playMove(save,currentnode->player);
            for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<=i;j++){
                    for(int k=0;k<=i;k++){
                        temp->board[i][j][k]=MCTBoard.a[i][j][k];
                    }
                }
            }
            temp->value=temp->visited=temp->win=temp->draw=0;
            temp->player=3-currentnode->player;
            return temp;
        }
    else{
        ///not important,and besides,I've not even reached here yet once.
    }
```

Or something to that effect.

Comment: Thanks a lot! To clear a few things up...The main reason why I used Node* knell because I thought freeing temp is needed...but based on your answer, Im predicting that it isnt needed after all.

Comment: One question: if you do temp=NULL and try to put sth in there, I know(from experimenting) that it crashes, but if you do temp=(Node*)nullptr  , why is it different? Why does it crash when I write NULL, but doesnt when I use nullptr?